# Why I can not copy a content of register to another one in “always” block in Verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog

well, I have this code, that is working perfectly:

```
module syncRX(clk, signal, detect);
    input clk, signal;
    output reg [7:0] detect = 0;
    reg [7:0] delay = 0;
    
    //wire clk_1khz;
    freq_div div(.clk(clk), .clk_1khz(clk_1khz));
    
    always @(posedge signal)
     begin
        detect <= detect + 1;
        delay <= 0;
     end
    
    always @(posedge clk_1khz)
     begin
        delay <= delay + 1;
     end
    
endmodule // top

module freq_div(input clk, output reg clk_1khz);
    reg [12:0] count = 0;
    always @(posedge clk)
     begin
        if(count == 6000)
            begin
                clk_1khz <= ~clk_1khz;
                count <= 0;
            end
        else
            count <= count + 1;
     end
    
endmodule
```

The problem appears when I change the line "detect <= detect + 1;" to "detect <= delay;". The intention is calculate the period of the signal, but I get this warning message of Icestorm: Warning: No clocks found in design

And the FPGA stop working... Please, anyone have an idea what is going bad? Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your real problem is that you are trying to load the `delay` flip-flops on two different edges, `signal` and `clk_1khz`. Such a flip-flop is (generally) not synthesizable, so the tools will throw an error if you try to do it. You will need to figure out a way to accomplish your goal without assigning to the same reg in two different `always` blocks.

Comment: Thanks Elliot, I am trying to do that, but no any idea is comming... Any suggestion?

Comment: Make all 3 of your processes use  always @(posedge clk). Register 'signal' into the 'clk' domain in one process. Don't generate a new clk_1khz - instead create a pulse in the the 'clk' domain that flips at the 1kHz rate. Once all flops are in the same clock domain everything is smooth sailing.

Comment: This make sense, thanks a lot!